# Validation Input Fields on Form Complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I created a Contact form with PHP but I made the submit button send the information through an Ajax script so my form won't close after fields are all completed and the user push send.

But now my problem is that even if the fields are empty the PHP won't send the error messages so the user can see them. My question is how can I use echo json_encode to make PHP send the error messages in case the fields are empty or they are not written as they should be?

The information is sent through Ajax script and the validation is inside PHP.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myModal").modal('hide');
  $('#contact-submit').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
     url:"forms.php",
      type:'post',
      data:$('#contact').serializeArray(),
      success:function(data){
      $("#myElem").show();
setTimeout(function() {$ ("#myElem").hide();}, 5000);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$numeprodus_error = $marime_error = $nume_error = $prenume_error = $adresa_error = $oras_error = $codpostal_error = $email_error = $telefon_error = "";
$numeprodus = $marime = $nume = $prenume = $adresa = $oras = $codpostal = $email = $telefon = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["numeprodus"])) {
    $numeprodus_error = "Numele este Obligatoriu!";
  } else {
    $nume = test_input($_POST["numeprodus"]);
    // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$numeprodus)) {
      $numeprodus_error = "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
    }
  }


    if (empty($_POST["marime"])) {
      $marime_error = "Selectati marimea!";
    } else {
      $nume = test_input($_POST["marime"]);
      // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$marime)) {
        $marime_error = "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
      }
    }


      if (empty($_POST["nume"])) {
        $nume_error = "Numele este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $nume = test_input($_POST["nume"]);
        // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nume)) {
          $nume_error = "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
        }
      }


      if (empty($_POST["adresa"])) {
        $adresa_error = "Adresa este obligatorie!";
      } else {
        $adresa = test_input($_POST["adresa"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9.]/i",$adresa)) {
          $adresa_error = "";
        }
      }


        if (empty($_POST["oras"])) {
          $oras_error = "Orasul este obligatoriu!";
        } else {
          $oras = test_input($_POST["oras"]);
          // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
          if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$oras)) {
            $oras_error = "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
          }
        }

      if (empty($_POST["codpostal"])) {
        $codpostal_error = "Codul postal este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $codpostal = test_input($_POST["codpostal"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/[0-9.]/i",$codpostal)) {
          $codpostal_error = "Doar cifre sunt permise in acest camp!";
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Emailul este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $email_error = "Email Invalid! Exemplu: ----@gmail.com";
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["telefon"])) {
        $telefon_error = "Numarul de Telefon este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $telefon = test_input($_POST["telefon"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$telefon)) {
          $telefon_error = "Numar de telefon Invalid! Minimum 10 Cifre!";
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
      } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
      }

      if ($numeprodus_error == '' and $marime_error == '' and $nume_error == '' and $prenume_error == '' and $adresa_error == '' and $oras_error == '' and $codpostal_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $telefon_error == '' ){
          $message_body = '';
          unset($_POST['submit']);
          foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
              $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
          }

          $to = 'andreiccl24@gmail.com';
          $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
          if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
              $success = "Comanda a fost Trimisa, va vom contacta in maximum 24 ore pentru confirmarea ei!";
              $numeprodus = $marime = $nume = $prenume = $adresa = $oras = $codpostal = $email = $telefon = $message = $success = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Comanda prin Email</h3>
          <h6 style="text-align: center;">Dupa plasarea comenzi in maximum 24 ore ve-ti fi contactat Telefonic pentru confirmarea acesteia!!!</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <?php include('forms.php'); ?>
            <div class="container">
              <form id="contact" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <select class="form-input-field" placeholder="Nume Produs" type="text" name="numeprodus" value="<?= $numeprodus ?>" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Produse</option>
                  <option>A</option>
                  <option>B</option>
                  <option>C</option>
                  <option>D</option>
                  <option>E</option>
                  <option>F</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="error"><?= $numeprodus_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <select class="form-input-field" placeholder="Marimea" type="text" name="marime" value="<?= $marime_produs ?>" tabindex="2" autofocus>
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Marimi</option>
                  <option>S</option>
                  <option>M</option>
                  <option>L</option>
                  <option>XL</option>
                  <option>XXL</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="error"><?= $marime_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <input class="form-input-field" placeholder="Nume/Prenume" type="text" name="nume" value="<?= $nume ?>" tabindex="3" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $nume_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <input class="form-input-field" placeholder="Adresa" type="text" name="adresa" value="<?= $adresa ?>" tabindex="4" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $adresa_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <input class="form-input-field" placeholder="Oras" type="text" name="oras" value="<?= $oras ?>" tabindex="5" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $oras_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <input class="form-input-field" placeholder="Cod Postal" type="number" name="codpostal" value="<?= $codpostal ?>" tabindex="6" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $codpostal_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <input class="form-input-field" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="7">
                  <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup class="form_sup">*</sup>
                  <input class="form-input-field" placeholder="Telefon" type="number" name="telefon" value="<?= $telefon ?>" tabindex="8">
                  <span class="error"><?= $telefon_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <span class="form_span">Mesaj:</span>
                <fieldset>
                  <textarea cols="50" row="10" value="<?= $message ?>" name="message" tabindex="9">
                  </textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>

                </fieldset>
<div id="myElem" style="display:none">BV MA AI FACUTO</div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dv-atentionare"><h3 class="dv-att-h3">Atentie!</h3><h6 class="dv-att-p2">Aveti la dispozitie 48 ore de la plasarea comenzi pentru a o putea anula!</h6></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <input class="btn btn-default" name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" value="Trimite"></input>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Inchide</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added my PHP script inside the CSS since there is nowhere else to do it.

Thank you guys in advance. I will suport any advice and critisizm based on my work till now :)

Keep in mind that I am in the stage of learning this. So tips are always something im looking forward to so I can read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

When error is caused:

```
<?php
$errors = [];
//..
if (empty($_POST["marime"])) {
    $errors[] = "Selectati marimea!";
} else {
    $nume = test_input($_POST["marime"]);
    // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $marime)) {
        $errors[] = "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
    }
}

//...
echo json_encode($errors);
```

Comment: My errors are displaying if I turn my input button back to button, If I do the submit through PHP not Ajax they will appear but since I changed the button to and Input so the form won't disappear after clicking Submit, the error messages won't display no more

Answer (score 0):

Hey there my fellow romanian 
First you need to change your php to return json of the errors if any or of the success message:

```
<?php

$numeprodus = $marime = $nume = $prenume = $adresa = $oras = $codpostal = $email = $telefon = $message = $success = "";
$errors = [];
//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["numeprodus"])) {
    $errors[] = "Numele este Obligatoriu!";
  } else {
    $nume = test_input($_POST["numeprodus"]);
    // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$numeprodus)) {
      $errors[]= "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
    }
  }


    if (empty($_POST["marime"])) {
      $errors[]= "Selectati marimea!";
    } else {
      $nume = test_input($_POST["marime"]);
      // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$marime)) {
        $errors[]= "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
      }
    }


      if (empty($_POST["nume"])) {
        $nume_error = "Numele este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $nume = test_input($_POST["nume"]);
        // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nume)) {
          $errors[]= "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
        }
      }


      if (empty($_POST["adresa"])) {
        $errors[]= "Adresa este obligatorie!";
      } else {
        $adresa = test_input($_POST["adresa"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9.]/i",$adresa)) {
          $adresa_error = "";
        }
      }


        if (empty($_POST["oras"])) {
          $errors[]= "Orasul este obligatoriu!";
        } else {
          $oras = test_input($_POST["oras"]);
          // check if nume only contains letters and whitespace
          if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$oras)) {
            $errors[]= "Doar litere sunt permise in acest camp!";
          }
        }

      if (empty($_POST["codpostal"])) {
        $errors[]= "Codul postal este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $codpostal = test_input($_POST["codpostal"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/[0-9.]/i",$codpostal)) {
          $errors[]= "Doar cifre sunt permise in acest camp!";
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $errors[]= "Emailul este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $errors[]= "Email Invalid! Exemplu: ----@gmail.com";
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["telefon"])) {
        $errors[]= "Numarul de Telefon este Obligatoriu!";
      } else {
        $telefon = test_input($_POST["telefon"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$telefon)) {
          $errors[]= "Numar de telefon Invalid! Minimum 10 Cifre!";
        }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
      } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
      }

      if (count($errors)) {
          $message_body = '';
          unset($_POST['submit']);
          foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
              $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
          }

          $to = 'andreiccl24@gmail.com';
          $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
          if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
              $success = "Comanda a fost Trimisa, va vom contacta in maximum 24 ore pentru confirmarea ei!";
              echo json_encode(['message'=>$success]);
      } else {
             echo json_encode(['message'=>$errors,'errors'=>true]);
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Next in your js you need to output the result of your ajax request, i used here a alert box , you may use a modal or something else

```
$('#contact-submit').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url:"forms.php",
          type:'post',
          data:$('#contact').serialize(),
          success:function(data){
          $("#myElem").show();
    setTimeout(function() {$ ("#myElem").hide();}, 5000);

          if(data.errors) {
            alert('Avem erori'+data.message)
          } else {
            alert('Mesaj de la ajax:'+data.message)
           }
         }
        })

 })
```

Don't forget to prevent the default click event

Comment: The console brings me a if error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: And if I make the PHP forms like that It will send me only the Field Names to the email not the content of the input field

Comment: Unexpected end of Input. first time I see this error :)

Comment: @AndreiCCL is your page refreshing ?

Comment: i see you are sanitising the values and then in the email your are sending the unsanitized values,why?

Comment: Don't really know what to answer to this question

Comment: @AndreiCCL the first question or the second one ?

Comment: My page is not refreshing cuz I made my button with type="button" not submit. Not even my modal closes anymore.

Comment: that means your ajax isn't working correctly, can you post a screenshot of your xhr request header and body?

Comment: I made it work this way. I want it not to close the modal or refresh the page

Comment: Can't see alert I have another console error end of input. and now its not sending me the data to the email anymore

Comment: Yea trying to see from where now

Comment: not working like this. There has to be a way making it work from the code I made

Comment: nothing but It seems its not sending me to email what I need and the messages are still not working

Comment: because your ajax isn't working,can you post the xhr request?

Comment: I don't haven on its empty

Comment: This is with my form script and code and jquery https://imgur.com/a/FWHdq